# How to know the app name which is in foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios8.1

Is it possible to get the app name which is in foreground mode? I could not find code anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

With Public API's it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS:-
As per my knowledge and experience, it's not available.

For OS-X:-
With use of the `NSWorkspace` class and `runningApplications` you can get the running applications.

Please check below documentation of NSWorkspace:-
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/runningApplications

Comment: `NSWorkspace` is available on OS X, not iOS.

Comment: I gave the answer only because to share some knowledge and may be person can get idea from this also.